# when().thenReturn() not returning service layer method call

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I'm having an issue where when I try `when(linkingTicketsService.getLinkedTicketDetails(list)).thenReturn(linkingTicketsResponseList);` in my test, it is still running the linkingTicketsService.getLinkedTicketDetails(list) method, shouldn't it just be retuning to mock I have prepared and NOT running the method itself? Ive tried Autowiring the LinkingTicketsService that I see in a previous post but it did not help any, any advice? thanks

Test Code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = LinkingTicketsService.class)
public class LinkingTicketsServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    LinkingTicketsService linkingTicketsService;

    @Mock
    WorkOrdersHierarchyRepo workOrdersHierarchyRepo;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        linkingTicketsService = new LinkingTicketsService(
                workOrdersHierarchyRepo,
                workOrderPTRViewRepo,
                ticketEngagementRepo,
                productMasterRepo
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void getLinkedTicketsByTicketNumber() {

        WorkOrderPTRView workOrderPTRView1 = new WorkOrderPTRView();
etc...

        Optional<WorkOrderPTRView> workOrderPTRViewOptional =  Optional.of(workOrderPTRView1);

        List<LinkingTicketsResponse> linkingTicketsResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
        LinkingTicketsResponse response = new LinkingTicketsResponse();
etc...

        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(123L);

        when(workOrderPTRViewRepo.findWorkOrderPTRViewByPartnerTicketNumber("567")).thenReturn(workOrderPTRViewOptional);
        when(linkingTicketsService.getLinkedTicketDetails(list)).thenReturn(linkingTicketsResponseList);

        LinkingTicketsResponse linkingTicketsResponse = linkingTicketsService.getLinkedTicketsByTicketNumber("567");
        assertThat(linkingTicketsResponse.getPartnerTicketNumber(), equalTo("123"));
    }
}
```

Methods:

```
    public LinkingTicketsResponse getLinkedTicketsByTicketNumber(String ticketNumber) {

        List<LinkingTicketsResponse> linkingTicketsResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
        Optional<WorkOrderPTRView> workOrderPTRViewOptional;

        //getting work order number
        workOrderPTRViewOptional = workOrderPTRViewRepo.findWorkOrderPTRViewByPartnerTicketNumber(ticketNumber);
        if (workOrderPTRViewOptional.isPresent()) {
            List<Long> workOrderNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
            workOrderNumbers.add(workOrderPTRViewOptional.get().getOrderId());

            linkingTicketsResponseList = getLinkedTicketDetails(workOrderNumbers);
        } else {
            LinkingTicketsResponse linkingTicketsResponse = new LinkingTicketsResponse();
            linkingTicketsResponse.setStatusCode(200);
            linkingTicketsResponse.setStatus("Failed.");
            linkingTicketsResponse.setStatusMessage("Could not find record for Work Order PTR");
            linkingTicketsResponseList.add(linkingTicketsResponse);
        }
        return linkingTicketsResponseList.get(0);
    }
```

Comment: Array in setup is different reference to one used in method under test so the matcher does not match and thus returns null when invoked. Loosen the expected match and it should work.

Comment: @Nkosi I changed it to `when(linkingTicketsService.getLinkedTicketDetails(anyList())).thenReturn(linkingTicketsResponseList);` and I'm still getting the NPE? Not sure what is happening?

Comment: @Nkosi it is getting a NPE on `if (workOrderPTRViewOptional.isPresent())` because  `workOrderPTRViewOptional ` is null but none of the method `public LinkingTicketsResponse getLinkedTicketsByTicketNumber(String ticketNumber)` should be running?

Comment: Why do you think it should not be running? You have an explicit call of it in your test (with ticketNumber "567"). -- Also your example does not show the definiton of `workOrderPTRViewRepo` for your test?

Comment: `linkingTicketsService` should be your class under test. You should not mock it (and according to your example code you do not). Using it in a `when` expression should fail.

Comment: Well not really, I'm testing a certain method in my class, not the whole class itself. That should stand to reason that I can mock any/all other methods that are NOT being tested correct? How does one go about mocking a method from the same class? I don't want it to actually run?